# Will running yum update while running createrepo cause a race condition?

Tags: yum

Our team has a locally hosted yum repository. At the end of our build process Jenkins:

- creates a new RPM
- moves the new RPM to the yum server's directory containing the rpms
- runs createrepo on our yum repository

If someone runs `yum update` during any of the above steps, what will happen? More specifically:

- What happens if yum update is ran while createrepo is updating the repo.?
- If yum update is being ran on an older version of an RPM, but createrepo removes and adds a new RPM version, what happens?

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not a race condition but a client side error due to inconsistent data.

A repository has a file which holds the list of items/packages contained within it.  That file is created/updated at the end of the repository creation/update.

If a client opens the repo and reads the contents file while this is being written to, their `yum` will bail out with an error.

If the file is not being written to but you are changing repo contents then the data can be inconsistent.  The `yum` client will bail out because a file references in the contents file is not readable.

If you wish to minimize problems you could work on a copy of the repo (depending on its size);

```
# rm -fr newrepo oldrepo
# rsync -ua repo/ newrepo/
# cd newrepo
(then update this copy or the repository)
# cd ..
# mv repo oldrepo; mv newrepo repo
# rm -fr oldrepo
```

This will make the changeover time shorter though it will not completely avoid client errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So basically, an obvious client side error will occur and the rpm won't install? The user can than wait for createrepo to finish, try yum udpate again, and all should work fine?

Comment: @TravisN Yes there will be an error message client-side but next time when they try again it will work again. Yum downloads all RPMs before starting to install and that step fails meaning their system will be remain OK - albeit outdated.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to test and give feedback, vote up and accept if the answer is correct.